# How to draw a sample of n elements from std::set

Tags: c++

I have the following function to pick a random element from a `std::set`:

```
int pick_random(const std::set<int>& vertex_set) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::set<int>::size_type> dist(0, vertex_set.size() - 1);
  const std::set<int>::size_type rand_idx = dist(mt);
  std::set<int>::const_iterator it = vertex_set.begin();
  for (std::set<int>::size_type i = 0; i < rand_idx; i++) {
    it++;
  }
  return *it;
}
```

However, I wonder how to properly draw a sample of `n` elements from a set. With C++17 compiler I can use `std::sample` function, but this is not the case here because I have C++11 compiler.

Comment: You could look at the source for `std::sample`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind the copy, an easy way is to create a `std::vector` from your `std::set`, shuffle it using [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and then takes the first `n` elements:

```
std::vector<int> pick_random_n(const std::set<int>& vertex_set, std::size_t n) {
    std::vector<int> vec(std::begin(vertex_set), std::end(vertex_set));
    std::shuffle(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), mt);
    vec.resize(std::min(n, vertex_set.size()));
    return vec;
}
```

If you do not want the extra-copy, you could look at the implementation of [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample), from, e.g., [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/a12cb9d211019d99b5875b6d8034617cbc24c2cc/include/algorithm#L3131) and implement your own for `std::set`:

```
std::vector<int> pick_random_n(const std::set<int>& vertex_set, std::size_t n) {
    auto unsampled_sz = vertex_set.size();
    auto first = std::begin(vertex_set);

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(std::min(n, unsampled_sz));

    for (n = std::min(n, unsampled_sz); n != 0; ++first) {
        auto r =
            std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>(0, --unsampled_sz)(mt);
        if (r < n) {
            vec.push_back(*first);
            --n;
        }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: The second algorithm is "Algorithm S" from D.Knuth TAOCP vol.2 sec 3.4.2.